# ColdFusion ORM Call method from EntityLoad in cfscript

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

I am trying to do something that I thought was pretty basic but I cannot get it to work. I am calling the EntityLoad like this:

```
<cfscript>

   transaction {

       dataLoad = EntityLoad("trans");  
   }

</cfscript>
```

Now if I do it tag based I can loop through it and call the methods like this:

```
<cfloop array="#dataLoad#" index="x">

    <cfoutput>#x.getCompanyName()#</cfoutput>

</cfloop>
```

But I am trying to do this in cfscript. The closest thing I can come up with is:

```
<cfscript>

    for (x=1;x <= ArrayLen(dataLoad);x=x+1){

        writeOutPut(dataLoad.companyName());            

    }

</cfscript>
```

I know that the for loop in cfscript is not the same as the cfloop array. There is not a equivalent to cfloop array in cfscript is there?

If not how can I call the methods in a EntityLoad from cfscript?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Below are 2 different ways to do this. Both of which I should have known. I gave the answer to Sam because it was the simplest and the least amount of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for ( var x in dataLoad ) {
 x.getCompanyName();
}
```

Comment: Using for ( x in array ) is new in CF9, in case you are wondering why it wont run on your CF6/7/8 instance

Comment: If you are using cfscript transactions, safe to presume you're already running CF9 :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

writeOutPut(dataLoad.companyName());

with

writeOutPut(dataLoad[x].getCompanyName());

That should fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<cfscript>

transaction {
    dataLoad = entityLoad("trans");
}

for ( var i = 1; i <= arrayLen( dataLoad ); i++ ) {
    writeOutput( dataLoad[i].companyName() );
}

</cfscript>
```

In cfscript when looping over an array, you need to specify the index on each iteration.